# Place page(linked) in a sidebar using google script

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-docs

Hello I wonder if it's possible because I've done the example of a sidebar in the google script tutorial I've put a link to google website when we click a tab is opened with the google search [image]
[image]
My question is it would be possible to click and have the google page search in the sidebar and do a search right there? Thank you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    Click <a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">here</a> for a google search
    <input type="button" value="Ferme"
        onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I’d try using google.script.run and urlFetch. Return search results to success handler.

Comment: Thanks I did this :<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      google.script.run.doSomething();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html> and after that in Code.gs i call the function function doSomething() {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://www.google.com/");
 Logger.log(response.getContentText());

} but I want the webpage of the Google in the sidebar there is other function to call in order tot get the webpage

Comment: Don't know what your final intention is, but Google Docs already allows you to make a Google search in a sidebar with the "Explore" tool. Also read Google's TOS to verify if you are allowed to embed it in other pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script will take the search phrase from the input box and open a new tab with the results:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">

    <script>
      function doSearch() {
        var searchFor = document.getElementById("txtSearchFor").value;

        window.open("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + searchFor);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <H1>Sidebar</H1>

    <input type="text" id="txtSearchFor"/>
    <input type="button" value="Search" id="btnSearch" onclick="doSearch()"/>

  </body>
</html>
```

If you want to actually do something with the results then you should look at using the [google custom search](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/tutorial/introduction) api which is a bit more involved.

Comment: Thank you very much!My idea is to do the search in the sidebar to avoid to open a new tab and to have finally the google webpage in the sidebar as an interactive tool to search and come back to other pages etc.